# Why am I not able to see icons in my website?

Tags: css

I am using this code as below

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('/../fonts/icomoon.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/../fonts/icomoon.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: you need to include the HTML code in which you are embedding this CSS.

Comment: Is your URL pointing on the good folders ?
Did you add the font-family 'icomoon' on the elements you want display icons with ?

Comment: You url is wrong. Either use relative `..` or absolute. You are using both :)

Answer (score 0):

if i use this code

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('icon-fonts/icomoon.html');
    src:url('icon-fonts/icomoond41d.html?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('icon-fonts/icomoon-2.html') format('truetype'),
        url('icon-fonts/icomoon-3.html') format('woff'),
        url('icon-fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

error shows in hosting server and runs normal in local system

[image]